# Не вносятся данные в БД. C#, WinForm выдает ошибку в if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)

Tags: c#, mysql

Ошибка: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1"
Вроде все делал правильно, но не может отправить данные.

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using static System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles.VisualStyleElement;

namespace Проект
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Close();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Double a;
            Double b;
            Double c;
            Double d;
            Double s;
            Double t;
            a = Convert.ToDouble(text1sem.Text);
            b = Convert.ToDouble(text1kon.Text);
            c = Convert.ToDouble(text2sem.Text);
            d = Convert.ToDouble(text2kon.Text);
            s = Convert.ToDouble(textitog.Text);
            t = (a + b + c + d + s) / 5 * 20;
            Itog.Text = Convert.ToString(t);
            DB db = new DB();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `рейтинг успеваемости` (`Фамилия`, `Имя`, `Отчество`, `1 семестр`, `1 контрольная точка`, `2 семестр`, `2 контрольная точка`, `Итоговая аттестационная`, `Общий рейтинг`) VALUES (@Famaly, @Name, @otce, @1sem, @1kon, @2sem, @2kon, @ates, @reit", db.getConnection());
            command.Parameters.Add("@Famaly", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textfameli.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textname.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@otce", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textotces.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@1sem", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = text1sem.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@1kon", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = text1kon.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@2sem", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = text2sem.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@2kon", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = text2kon.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@ates", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = textitog.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@reit", MySqlDbType.Float).Value = Itog.Text;
            db.openConnection();
            if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
                MessageBox.Show("Данные сохранены");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Данные не сохранены");
            
            db.closeConnection();


        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `@reit)", ...`? Закрыть `VALUES ( ... )` забыли

Comment: Спасибо, помогло